# how to run python 'pyw' file in Windows 10 process

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, pythonw

Good Day All,

I finished writing the site blocker process and then i renamed the "py" file by appending "w", double clicked to run it yet the process did not show up in the task manager. I tried it a few times and yet nothing showed up. Mind you I am on Win 10 OS.

You have any suggestions to help fix this such that is shows up in the task manager as pythonw.exe process ?

Comment: Hey Matt, 

 you are absolutely correct there was a slight error now it runs fine in the background :)

Comment: Don't forget to select the answer that answered your question

Answer (score 0):

If the process isn't showing up in the Task Manager, it's very likely that it's immediately quitting with an error. Even trivial changes to the code cause this to occur. Without the console showing output it's hard to tell what that error is. Try renaming the file back to `filename.py` and running it to see if an error is occurring.

Another possibility is that the script is completing so fast you don't have time to see it. Did it run instantaneously when it was named `filename.py`?